# <p>Failed to decode JSON object: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 10 (char 9)</p>

Tags: python, flask, curl

```
@app.route('/tasks', methods=['POST'])
def create_task():
    if not request.json or not 'title' in request.json:
        abort(400)
    task = {
        'id': tasks[-1]['id'] + 1,
        'title': request.json['title'],
        'description': request.json.get('description', "HEY"),
        'done': False
    }
    tasks.append(task)
    return jsonify({'task': task}), 201
```

**CURL command:**

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{"""title""":"""Read a book"""}" http://localhost:5000/tasks
```

using **CURL** in local cmd. Please help me how to remove the error.

Answer (score -1):

try it:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"title\":\"Read a book\"}" http://localhost:5000/tasks
```